# How to solve this error: module 'gensim' has no attribute 'models'

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

I want to use gensim to train a word2vec model 
python 3.5.3 
gensim 2.1.0 
numpy 1.12.1+mkl 
scipy 0.19.0

```
import gensim
import codecs
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename=filename
    def __iter__(self):
        with codecs.open(self.filename) as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                wordlist=list()
                for word in line:
                    wordlist.append(word)
                yield wordlist

sentences=MySentences('D:/Documents/Data/icwb2-data-processed/pku_training.rmspace.utf8')
model=gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences)
model.save('w.model')
```

I run this code, and i cause the error:

> AttributeError: module 'gensim' has no attribute 'models'

I make this error due to i named this file 'gensim.py' 
thank @BurhanKhalid !!!

Comment: Try `from gensim.models import Word2Vec`,  then replace `model=gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences)` with `model=Word2Vec(sentences)` does it work then?

Comment: Don't save your file as `gensim.py`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  you are right！thank you！

Answer (score 2):

In python, it may cause an error if your code module's name writing by yourself is the same as library module name.

So you shouldn't name your training file as "gensim.py" which would override the gensim library file: "gensim.py"

Answer (score 1):

You have to import models from gensim.

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/